# Forgot to backup my database before reinstalling WAMP

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I uninstalled and reinstalled my WAMP earlier today. I backed up my /www directory but totally forgot about my database (phpmyadmin). I didn't delete my C:/wamp directory, i just reinstalled on top of it.

Does this mean my databases are gone forever? Is there a way to retrieve them? Next time i'll know to export a dump of my databases before I meddle with the installation, I guess I had to learn this the hard way...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends if you deleted the data directory or not. By default, wamp's data directory is `c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.x.x/data` check there and see if you have some folders with the names of your old databases. In those folders there would be a bunch of .frm, .MYD, and .MYI files assuming you are using myisam. If those files exist then you can recover. Just make sure the datadir in my.ini is pointing to the directory where your database are and restart mysql. It should fix itself automatically.

If you use innodb tables then it's a little more complicated but can be done. Those would be stored in files named ibdata1, ibdata2, etc.

If you don't have any of those files then I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Yup so my tables (or atleast some) are stored in the data subfolder! Seemed that the reinstall installed a new mySQL version (5.5.20) over the old version (5.5.16). But when I point the datadir to 5.5.16, my wamp doesn't seem to load completed (icon doesn't turn green). When i hit localhost/phpmyadmin, it throws an error that it can't connect to the server socket. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You should check your mysql error log. It could be that you just need to delete your ibdata files or ib_logfile files and let mysql recreate them on connect. I would move them out of there into another folder and try restarting it again.

Comment: I've moved those folders out of the directory but it still doesn't work. My error that seems to stop the execution of mysql is Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist. I'm looking around for a direct and simple solution, would you know of one? I hope you don't mind me picking at your brain like this..

Comment: I got the green icon when switching to my old mysql version by reinstalling the beta version of wamp which happened to have the required version. Unfortunately, not all table are retrievable at the moment. Of the .frm files, only the ones with MYD and MYI files are visible in my phpmyadmin interface. All the other .frm files without MYD and MYI are not recognized. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You could try renaming the the .frm and ibdata files, creating the databases manually so the .frm files are recreated (and ibdata recreated on mysql restart). The stop mysql, move your files back in to replace the ones mysql created (with the correct names) and start mysql back up. This may work and it may not. I've done it in the past but ibdata files don't always work with different versions of mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to retrieve mine on windows 7 by doing the following

Open Computer by clicking the Start button , and then clicking Computer.

Navigate to the folder that used to contain the file or folder c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.x.x/data

Copied it just in case I needed to revert

Right-click it, and then click Restore previous versions. ...

Double-click a previous version of the folder that contains the file or folder you want to restore.

Comment: wow thanks alot you've saved me 2 days worth of work! I have a small question - how do I restore my databases? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: UPDATE: Figured it out. I just reinstalled wamp and went to the new mysql data folder and replaced it with the old mysql data (overwrite anything already there.)
That whole time, my wamp server is off.
I then opened wamp server, and switched on (server online) and VOILA!!! IT WORKS :)